# Write NSData in half bytes

Tags: ios, hex, nsdata

I need to write a hex string to NSData but I am getting an extra zero appended to the end and it is causing me some issues.  Is there a way to write half bytes to NSData?

For example I am converting 100010002 and I am getting 100010002**0** (extra zero).

This is what I am using to convert the hex string to NSData. Thanks.

```
    + (NSData *)dataFromHexString:(NSString*)stringToConvert {
    const char *chars = [stringToConvert UTF8String];
    int i = 0;
    int len = (int)[stringToConvert length];
    
    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:len / 2];
    char byteChars[3] = {'\0','\0','\0'};
    unsigned long wholeByte;
    
    while (i < len) {
        byteChars[0] = chars[i++];
        byteChars[1] = chars[i++];
        wholeByte = strtoul(byteChars, NULL, 16);
        [data appendBytes:&wholeByte length:1];
    }
    
    return data;
}
```

Comment: A hex string is supposed to have an even number of characters, your example has 9.

Comment: That is kind of what I figured but I was't sure.  Thanks.